# Is there any way to map Dictionary<int, List<AClass>> in EFCore?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I have a class:

```
class A 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public Dictionary<int,List<B>> Mapping { get; set; } // int is an arbitrary value, not FK from B
}

class B 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
}
```

Is it possible to use EF Core so it does create association table between `A` and `B` but accessible through the `Dictionary`.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of what EF Core is supposed to do, it is supposed to map to your database, so doing this would not make a lot of sense.

Comment: @DavidG You jumped to a conclusion quite quickly. For instance EF could create association table and filter it on reading.... the question is about if this is possible in EF core, this is "mappable" to DB but I don't know if EF supports it.

Comment: Then make your class structure mimic the database structure. If you really need to map to a dictionary, do that outside of the bounds of the DbContext

Comment: @DavidG This is why this question was posted, I'm lazy and there is too much code and tests to be changed, I don't want to do it and `Dictionary` is much more suitable in   my scenario.